# How to stop Lambda Step functions execution as Bulk (stop multiple executions at once)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I created a Lambda Step Function flow that on one step it will wait until that step is resumed by callback Token. For testing purposes, I invoke the step function 1000 times.
600 invocations completed successfully but 400 are still in running state (because the process failed of DB connection fail) and I know that it will never resume.
How can I stop the functions in bulk?
Currently, I see only one option to stop execution on every single execution, but i have to do it 400 times which is a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop all running Step Functions of a specific state machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64845076/how-to-stop-all-running-step-functions-of-a-specific-state-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to @Pål Brattberg

aws stepfunctions list-executions 
--state-machine-arn <STEP FUNCTION ARN> 
--status-filter RUNNING 
--query "executions[*].{executionArn:executionArn}" 
--output text | 
xargs -I {} aws stepfunctions stop-execution 
--execution-arn {}

More info [How to stop all running Step Functions of a specific state machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64845076/how-to-stop-all-running-step-functions-of-a-specific-state-machine)